# Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, amazon-s3

I am developing a website in HTML, javascript & jQuery. I want to upload images to amazon s3 server in an ajax request. There is no such SDK to integrate s3 in Javascript. A PHP SDK is available, but it is not useful to me. Can anybody provide solution to this in javascript?

Comment: you should really change the accepted answer on this question since it is now possible.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Got Amazon S3 & CORS working on js and html5 using XMLHTTPObject based on this article [article](http://bencoe.tumblr.com/post/30685403088/browser-side-amazon-s3-uploads-using-cors).

1: CORS only works from a proper URL "http://localhost". (file///xyz will make you go insane)

2 : Make sure you got the POLICY and Secret compiled correctly - here is my policy and this is the link you can get the project to get you started with [Signature and Policy](http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/01/save-an-image-file-directly-to-s3-from-a-web-browser-using-html5-and-backbone-js/)  -- do not publish this JS with your Secret EVER!

```
POLICY_JSON = { "expiration": "2020-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
            "conditions": [
            {"bucket": this.get('bucket')},
            ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
            {"acl": this.get('acl')},                           
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
            ["content-length-range", 0, 524288000]
            ]
          };


    var secret = this.get('AWSSecretKeyId');
    var policyBase64 = Base64.encode(JSON.stringify(POLICY_JSON));
    console.log ( policyBase64 )

    var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);
    b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);
    console.log( signature);
```

Here is the JS code

```
function uploadFile() {

    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();

    var key = "events/" + (new Date).getTime() + '-' + file.name;

    fd.append('key', key);
    fd.append('acl', 'public-read'); 
    fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);      
    fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', 'YOUR ACCESS KEY');
    fd.append('policy', 'YOUR POLICY')
    fd.append('signature','YOUR SIGNATURE');

    fd.append("file",file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://<yourbucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/', true); //MUST BE LAST LINE BEFORE YOU SEND 

    xhr.send(fd);
  }
```

Helper functions

```
function uploadProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
  }

  function uploadComplete(evt) {
    /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
    alert("Done - " + evt.target.responseText );
  }

  function uploadFailed(evt) {
    alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file." + evt);
  }

  function uploadCanceled(evt) {
    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
  }
```

Then the HTML Form

```
 <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="row">
  <label for="file">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="fileSelected()"/>
</div>
<div id="fileName"></div>
<div id="fileSize"></div>
<div id="fileType"></div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
</div>
<div id="progressNumber"></div>
```

Happy CORS-ing!

Comment: Hi folks. This looks like exactly what I'm looking for to upload to my S3 bucket. However, I'm stumped on the first part (ironically, the rest of it looks straight-forward). I'm a total newb when it comes to S3 and to be honest I just don't know what to do with the POLICY_JSON code. In short: where do I put this?

Comment: Just found this article that explains the anatomy of an AWS upload form in detail: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Comment: What file are you using to define Base64?

Comment: Agree. took me a while to get there googling it, but at last!

Comment: Props for a clean, library-independent answer!

Comment: My `evt.target.responseText` is always blank, do you know why? Furthermore, how can I get the url of uploaded file? thanks!

Comment: how do you apply this if I'm using temporary credentials, those who have session token to include.?

Comment: This post could definitely be improved if the author would consider explaining what they're doing in the first code example. The link that is referenced has a similar example in Ruby, Java and Python. Biggest problem is, the author neglected to say which libraries are used for Base64 and Crypto. (standard node crypto should work)

Comment: Jim- That's right - I used Base64 to get this to work -

Comment: @JimWharton you need to get the variables filled from your AWS policy file. Get this project here running https://github.com/tweetegy/save_image_directly_to_s3_using_backbone so you will understand where those variables come from.

Comment: It would be awesome if anyone  has this converted to  angular'!

Comment: @BenjiXVI this solution does not require any server side logic.  Please revisit code and methodology above before drawing your conclusion.

Comment: @fino I’m confused – either you publish your AWS secret (discouraged) or you sign the form server-side? Which are you advocating, or have I missed something?

Comment: @BenjiXVI You only use the first part of the example to create your "signature" in your private environment..you never ever publish that code. The first part of the post (getting the signature) is super private and u never upload it anywhere. After you get that setup you use that "signature" from this line (var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);) publicly in conjunction with your AWSAccessKeyId, Policy --- Following these steps, you will never have to share your AWS Secret.

Comment: OK, I hadn’t considered that you can generate that part offline. It’s important to note, though, that often you need to regenerate the signature dynamically – for instance, whenever the expiration date changes. But pre-generating it could be useful in some cases, yeah.

Comment: Where does `b64_hmac_sha1` come from?

Comment: part of the base library - https://github.com/tweetegy/save_image_directly_to_s3_using_backbone/blob/master/libs/sha1.js

Comment: `var xhr = getXMLHTTPObject();` should be `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` good script, shame we still need to use crappy iframes for IE8 and 9

Comment: `fileSelected` is not implemented AFAICT.

Comment: If this is a script for a public-facing site, I recommend you generate a temporary signature/policy on the server side for each new upload, which then expires at some time in the future.  See [this article](https://leonid.shevtsov.me/post/demystifying-s3-browser-upload/)

Comment: @fino Hi Thanks but i am facing this issue on firefox RequestTimeout Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed and file is does not upload on S3.Can you please help me on how can i fix this issue.Thanks

Comment: I have also opened a issue at GitHub please take a look on this Thanks it will be really helpful. github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1332

Comment: @usama please check for backward js compatibility on my solution as it is now about 5 years old. Some core function calls might have changed.

Comment: Thanks @fino  and can you please guide me a little bit how can i check backward js compatibility.

Comment: What if you don't use hard coded access keys and secret keys? What if you're using IAM Roles (which don't have Access/Secret Keys? What do you use in place of them?

Answer (score 7):

Amazon just allowed Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, in theory it allows your users to upload to S3 directly, without using your server (and PHP) as a proxy.

Heres the docs -> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

They do a great job of telling you how to enable it on an S3 bucket, but iv found no actual javascript examples of how to get data from client to bucket.

First person to post CORS.js is a legend xD

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by AWS S3 Cognito try this link here :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Amazon_S3

**Also try this code**

Just change Region, IdentityPoolId and Your bucket name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>AWS S3 File Upload</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
    <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.region = 'your-region'; // 1. Enter your region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'your-IdentityPoolId' // 2. Enter your identity pool
    });
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if (err) alert(err);
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
    });
    var bucketName = 'your-bucket'; // Enter your bucket name
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
    });
    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var file = fileChooser.files[0];
        if (file) {
            results.innerHTML = '';
            var objKey = 'testing/' + file.name;
            var params = {
                Key: objKey,
                ContentType: file.type,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
            bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
                } else {
                    listObjs(); // this function will list all the files which has been uploaded
                    //here you can also add your code to update your database(MySQL, firebase whatever you are using)
                }
            });
        } else {
            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
        }
    }, false);
    function listObjs() {
        var prefix = 'testing';
        bucket.listObjects({
            Prefix: prefix
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
            } else {
                var objKeys = "";
                data.Contents.forEach(function(obj) {
                    objKeys += obj.Key + "<br>";
                });
                results.innerHTML = objKeys;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If needed you can use [github Link](https://github.com/rishiv3/s3-multiple-file-upload-angularJS)

I hope it will help others :)

Comment: I am getting a 403

Answer (score 0):

For the authentication part,

No php code, no server, no large JS code except below;

you might use AWS Cognito IdentityPoolId as credential, less code
but you are required to create AWS Cognito IdetityPool and attach policy, simply s3 write access.

```
     var IdentityPoolId = 'us-east-1:1...........';


     AWS.config.update({
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
        })
     });
```

Comment: how can i get the IdentityPoolId can you please explain a little bit Thanks.

Comment: And simply allow everyone who sniffs out your Cognito token from a simple network traffic analyzer to get authorization to dump files in your S3 bucket for free continously without your control. Thats the cost of "no code no server no large JS"

Comment: you must forgotten there is thing like https

Comment: A Cognito token is yet another JWT token, i assume if you upload to a server whose security mechanism is the same it will be as prone to traffic analyzer as Cognito. Skipping the server for a largely bandwidth intensive task like uploading an binary image to s3 has its benefits and drawbacks. In general JWT tokens shouldn't be long lived, CORS settings at the S3 bucket should be sensible and not '*' on everything, Lambda post hook triggers can be setup at S3 to validate each upload are things that can be done to prevent unauthorized uploads.