# AWS S3 CORS upload - file size control

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-s3, cors, filesize

I'm planning to change my age old file upload routing to S3 using their [new CORS upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) api. But even before I've started, I've hit a roadblock. I can easily enough generate signed urls with auto expire and send it back to my client side script to start the upload. But how do I now limit the file sizes? I can't just add the restriction in my scripts. Is there a way to configure the file size while generating that signed URL? I use [BOTO](https://github.com/boto/boto) on python for the signing.

Comment: Hey Jibi, did you find a solution with boto? It would be great if you could share it. Thanks.

Comment: @Pasada I'll post my current solution soon. Need to clean it of internal mech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can include a signed policy (including a `content-length-range` value) as part of files uploaded via POST. Do either of these links help?

[Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n/12378395#12378395)

http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/01/save-an-image-file-directly-to-s3-from-a-web-browser-using-html5-and-backbone-js/
(This one doesn't actually include content-length-range in the policy, but you can add it.)

Comment: it does help. I'll just wait out a couple of more hours to see if anything better comes up. Thank you