# uploading images to amazon s3 bucket from windows 8 store app(Javascript)

Tags: amazon-s3, winjs

It seems that amazon S3 .NET SDK is not supported in windows 8 store apps because of some restrictions in WinRT.Is there any other work around? In case I use REST api, can i use the WinJS.xhr function to call and process the web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with the REST api. 
Check out:

[Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n)

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Note that in WinJS you DO NOT have to deal with CORS here as HTML/JS Windows Store apps do not have the cross domain restriction that you have in the browser.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

You can also test this out using Fiddler's composer (http://fiddler2.com/) to ensure you have the proper request and then recreate in your JavaScript