# How to handle many concurrent large file uploads on the server.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, concurrency

I have a new client that wants to create an app where there will be many users uploading images, probably at the same time.

I'm not sure what the best setup I should use for this. Should I try to setup another app to handle the image uploads so that the main app is not tied up?

I'm not that experienced with this type of scaling need.THis will probably be a Rails app, but maybe not if that wouldn't be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using S3 as your image store...)

Have you considered [uploading directly to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12378395/382982)?

Comment: Currently considering this, but I will need post processing on the images.

Comment: You could trigger a background job after the upload has completed.