# HTML POST -> redirect working, XMLHTTPrequest -> redirect not working (Cannot make any requests from null)?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I have a working HTML POST form to upload to Amazon S3:

```
<form action="https://bucketcwav.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="s3Name" type="hidden" name="key" value="images/${filename}">
  <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="%accesskey%">
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.mydomain.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="%policy%" />
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="%signature%" />
  <input id="mimetype" type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
  <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

  File to upload to S3: 
  <input id="fileinput" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
</form>
```

After a successful upload, http://www.mydomain.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php is called.

Now I tried to do change my code into using a XMLHTTPRequest because I need to do some javascript image resizing:

```
<body>
<div class="form" id="form">
      File to upload to S3: 
      <input id="fileinput" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*"><span id="progress"></span>
    </form> 

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('fileinput').onchange = function(event){
        var file = event.target.files[0]; // The files selected by the user (as a FileList object entry).
        event.target.files[0] = resizeAndUpload(event.target.files[0]);
        };
} else {
        alert('You are using an outdated browser. To get a better site experience, please update your browser to the latest version.');
}

//from http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop
function resizeAndUpload(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {

    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.src = reader.result;
    tempImg.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 768;
        var tempW = tempImg.width;
        var tempH = tempImg.height;
        if (tempW > tempH) {
            if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
               tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
               tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
               tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
               tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tempW;
        canvas.height = tempH;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);

        // from http://alipman88.github.io/debt/about/index.html
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9);
        var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append("key", "images/"+Math.floor((Math.random()+1)*1000000000000000)+".jpg");
        fd.append("AWSAccessKeyId", "%Accesskey%");
        fd.append("acl", "public-read");
        fd.append("success_action_redirect", "http://www.mydomain.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php");       
        fd.append("policy", "%policy%");
        fd.append("signature", "%signature%");
        fd.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        fd.append("file", blob);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://%bucket%.s3.amazonaws.com/");
        xhr.send(fd);
      }
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

//helperfunctions
    //from https://gist.github.com/kosso/4246840
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}

// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n
function uploadProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
  }

</script>
```

The uploading is just as successful, except that Chrome gives me an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mydomain.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php?bucket=bucket&k…=images%2F1028249253286048.jpg&etag=%226ca24feebab0daf48ffea90d16370868%22. Cannot make any requests from null.

In FF this code doesn't give me an error, but doesn't load imageloadsuccess.php either.
I'm quite new to programming so I might not see something very simple here, any help or alternative POST method is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE 1**: 
Perhaps this has something to do with it: https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=155002&view=revision

**UPDATE 2**: The Chrome console shows indeed that the origin is null, which is correct according to http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#redirect-steps. But it shouldn't block it. It is the bug as described in Update 1. But maybe someone can tell me why the redirect actually loads on the screen using HTML POST form, while only loading on the background when using XMLHTTPrequest?

```
On POST: 
Request URL:https://%bucket%.s3.amazonaws.com/
Request Headersview parsed
POST https://%bucket%.s3.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://%mydomain%.com/test2.html
Origin: http://%mydomain%.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.14 Safari/537.36

REDIRECT:
Request URL:http://www.%mydomain%.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php?bucket=%bucket%&key=images%2F1851413185242563.jpg&etag=%226ca24feebab0daf48ffea90d16370868%22
Request Headersview parsed
GET http://www.%mydomain%.com/PHP/imageloadsuccess.php?bucket=%bucket%&key=images%2F1851413185242563.jpg&etag=%226ca24feebab0daf48ffea90d16370868%22 HTTP/1.1
**Origin: null**
Referer: http://%mydomain%.com/test2.html
```

**UPDATE 3**:
Adding

```
xhr.onload = function() { console.log(["success", this]) };
xhr.onerror = function() { console.log(["error", this]) };
```

Shows an error in FF as well as Chrome, but both actually run the PHP file. So it seems everything is OK, but I still don't understand why the errors. In iOS6 safari, the loading wheel keeps spinning because of xhr.send(fd);
There must be something wrong with my XMLHTTPrequest, but I have no idea what. Sorry for the huge amount of text, hope somebody sees what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the redirect is blocked because of the CORS headers returned by your PHP script (it should respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`).

There's also an alternative solution. Instead of using the redirect to notify your app that the image has uploaded, you can do a separate AJAX request from your `success()` handler in the original S3 POST request (don't include the `success_action_redirect` field in the original request / the POST request is successful if S3 responds with a status code of 200 or 204).

Comment: Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null` to PHP: works great for the redirect part, didn´t know that was needed. 
The initial POST request however keeps acting weird when using success_action_redirect: Chrome displays the POST request as 'canceled' and iOS6 Safari thinks the request is never finished (loading wheel keeps spinning). FF handles it well.
So instead of the `success_action_redirect` I tried the `"success_action_status" = "200"` you mentioned with a separate AJAX request on `xhr.onload()` and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot, I was on this for days already.