# Error when importing large csv file to Rails app on AWS ECS container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, amazon-web-services, docker, heroku

I tried uploading a csv with 2700 rows and my service (running in a docker container on A.W.S) stopped running after a some seconds but the upload was complete (as all the data is present in my database). The logs (cloudwatch) do not show any error, instead the service is stopped and restarted (sometimes successfully and sometimes not).

I found a similar issue that Heroku has [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227380/error-when-uploading-large-file-with-paperclip-and-aws), where the answer says Heroku has a 30 second timeout on all request, does A.W.S have something similar? If not how can overcome this as CSV uploads are frequent at my workplace.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your docker container behind a load balancer? If so, is it an application load balancer?

Comment: @arvymetal yes, I found the issue, the health check fails because it seems rails 4.2.6 (on production) uses a single thread. During the read (CSV) and write (database), it cannot do anything else. I solved the issue by handling the upload and write with a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for uploading data in bulk amount. It does this job at background. Moreover I have run the issue where even sidekiq stopped if you face similar issue then I would recommend **God** gem for monitoring purpose for sidekiq. 
Regarding AWS timeout information kindly have a look on this. [Elastic Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/24/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-idle-timeout-configuration/)