# XUL: Direct upload to S3 but without using a file-input element

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a Firefox addon that needs to upload images from the local file system to S3 directly.

The examples I could find in AWS, SO etc. explain how this can be done for web pages using the standard file-input control for image transport (with other AWS specific request signing etc., which I've got working perfectly).

http://bencoe.tumblr.com/post/30685403088/browser-side-amazon-s3-uploads-using-cors

[Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n/12378395#12378395)

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

However, I couldn't find any info regarding how I can upload a file **without** using the file-input, I know the local absolute path to the file (the addon itself writes out the file before trying to upload it to S3).

After a few hours of trying to find the "proper" way, i thought of faking the file-input like below:

```
var fileInput = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","input");
fileInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
fileInput['files'] = [{
    mozFullPath: file.path,
    name: file.leafName,
    size: file.fileSize,
    type: 'image/gif' // testing only with gifs
}];
```

and then `fd.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);` where fd is my `FormData` object. And then POSTing it to s3 via AJAX.

This uploads the file to S3. However, when opening the file in my browser, I get the text `"undefined"` instead of the image.

Then i tried `fd.append("file", fileInput.files);` - This time the content returned by the browser instead of the image is the text `"[object FileList]"`

I'm stumped! I know it has got to do with trying to fake the file-input. I believe there should be a cleaner, more correct way of doping this.

Can anyone shed some light on how i can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `chrome` code (aka. privileged code) you can construct DOM File objects simply by just invoking the File constructor with a path:

```
var file = File("path/to/some/file");
fd.append("file", file);
```

For more information see: [Using the DOM File API in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that too as it seemed like the right way (forgot to include it in my question), but it doesn't work as well. S3 gives me the error `"MalformedPOSTRequest"`

Comment: Just to make sure: The exact same code does work when using a file input instead of `new File()`? How do the requests differ on the wire (Console w/ request logging and/or Network Panel for the lazy). You get a free `chrome` privileged page including all developer tools and Scratchpad by opening about:newtab, BTW... might be easier than fiddling with the actual add-on code. ;)

Comment: The DOM File approach indeed works. The error was a different one (just nailed it a couple minutes ago!). I was trying to upload the file too soon after writing it to disk (using `nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveUri`). I introduced a delay before uploading to ensure that the file is closed by saveUri's writer (since i couldn't find a close method in `nsIWebBrowserPersist`).

Comment: Yes, the scratchpad is indeed a life-saver for chrome environment. Tks for the pointers.