# DELETE files from S3 with CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor, xmlhttprequest, cors

Im storing images on Amazon S3. I have finally uploaded images (following the idea suggested here: [uploading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n)), with XMLHttpRequest, and it works very nicely.

Now Im trying to delete images from s3, but when I change the method on xml.open to 'DELETE', and send the form Amazon responds with a forbidden message.
I did enable upload/delete under permissions at AWS console, and edited the CORS config to include DELETE

Actually, right now, to send files to S3 Im using POST request, but PUT request doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the below in the config of CORS with POST?

```
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
```

Comment: yes I did.
finally a came up with an implementation. Ill post it here!

Comment: you'll post it where?

Comment: where did you post @zalavari ?