# Can't upload file to Amazon S3 in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-web-services

When i upload file to Amazon S3 i can't call function upload  I don't know why , Please help me. This my code

> Blockquote

var s3Uploader = (function() {
    var crypto = require('crypto'), secret = "My_AWSSecretKey", policy, policyBase64, signature;

```
policy = {
    "expiration" : "2020-12-31T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conditions" : [ {
        "bucket" : "MobileCommerce"
    }, [ "starts-with", "$key", "" ], {
        "acl" : 'public-read'
    }, [ "starts-with", "$Content-Type", "" ],
            [ "content-length-range", 0, 524288000 ] ]
};

policyBase64 = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(policy), 'utf8').toString('base64');
console.log("Policy Base64:");
console.log(policyBase64);
signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1',secret).update(policyBase64).digest('base64');
console.log("Signature:");
console.log(signature);

var s3URI = encodeURI("http://MobileCommerce.s3.amazonaws.com/"),
    awsKey = 'My_AWSAccessKey', 
    acl = "public-read";

function upload(imageURI, fileName) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred(), ft = new FileTransfer(), options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileName;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = {
        "key" : fileName,
        "AWSAccessKeyId" : awsKey,
        "acl" : acl,
        "policy" : policyBase64,
        "signature" : signature,
        "Content-Type" : "image/jpeg"
    };

    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI, function(e) {
        deferred.resolve(e);
    }, function(e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
    }, options);

    return deferred.promise();

}

return {
    upload : upload
}
```

}());

> Blockquote

and this is function capture photo and send photo to Amazon S3

> Blockquote

(function() {

```
var $img = $('img', '.scroller'),

// Take a picture using the camera
takePicture = function(e) {
    var options = {
        quality : 45,
        targetWidth : 1000,
        targetHeight : 1000,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {
        $img.attr('src', imageURI);
        var fileName = "" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".jpg";
        // consider a more reliable way to generate unique ids
        s3Uploader.upload(imageURI, fileName).done(function() {
            alert("S3 upload succeeded");
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("S3 upload failed");
        });
    }, function(message) {
        alert('abc');
        // We typically get here because the use canceled the photo
        // operation. Fail silently.
    }, options);

    return false;

};

$('.camera-btn').on('click', takePicture);
```

}());

> Blockquote

i use lib cordova-2.5.0.js . in html code

Answer (score 0):

Amazon just allowed Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, in theory it allows your users to upload to S3 directly, without using your server (and PHP) as a proxy.

so Here's an example of resumable file uploads on Amazon S3 using CORS and javascript

[refer](http://cotag.github.io/Condominios/)

and also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n) for more details