# Get image data from Html5 canvas and upload it to Amazon S3 server, using Scala

Tags: html, scala, canvas, amazon-s3

I am in a bit of trouble with uploading images on Amazon S3 servers,my objective goes like:

- Create image on Html5 canvas by dragging and dropping images in it,
- Then upload/save the image in Amazon S3 server.

**My app properly creates the image, and asks the user to save the image; with the help of JS libraries**

But the problem:

- I need to save them directly to S3 server, not on my local. I have been using java-aws sdk.

My own ideas,

- I could save the image on my local machine, and then upload using the java-aws-sdk but that would be a longer process i.e. saving in local and then uploading in s3 server.

`Is there any way to get the image-data or image to backend scala code and then converting it into some image obj (since java-aws seems to need a file to upload) and then I would be using java-aws sdk for the rest.`

Comment: Checkout this link [Uploading Image to Amazon s3 ][1] may be it will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n?rq=1

Comment: My problem is I would not be using forms.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: Have you seen the page about [body parsers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaBodyParsers) ? You can find some examples of that on the web. These are not mine, I just found them on manning forum:
[1](https://github.com/mslinn/AwsS3)
[2](https://github.com/mslinn/play21-file-upload-streaming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well i found my answer and much credit goes to this SO post, [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)**

```
def foo(source: String) {
        //Getting the base64 encoded string, then converting into byte stream
        val imgByte = Base64.decodeBase64(source)
        val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgByte)

        val bucketName = "SOME_BUCKET"
        val AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "KEY"   
        val AWS_SECRET_KEY = "SECRET"

        val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
        val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)
        val md = new ObjectMetadata

        amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, "fireside2.png", bis, md)
    }
```

Comment: though I have got much to research on the ObjectMetadata and getting the encoded string to my Scala method, Ajax and stuff ...., but for now it seems to work!!