# How to speed up image uploading carrierwave and Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am working with `Rails4 and carrierwave`, uploading the images and files to S3. But it's taking much time and very slow. How to handle this situation to speed up the server speed!!!

How to handle this using `Background Jobs` and Handle request from lot of users.
Also getting images is very slow into my application!!!

Can you suggest me how to achieve Rails severe works fast while uploading files?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider uploading directly from the client to S3 via Ajax. This would nearly completely take your server out of the mix.

[Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n)

This is a well documented concept elsewhere online.

Amazon S3 now has notifications for newly created objects.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

You could drop the upload notifications into an Amazon SQS queue. You could then use a gem like Fog to create a background worker to pull events off the queue to create or update records in the database to reflect the newly completed upload.

https://github.com/fog/fog

Regardless of the solution, if you're uploading big files, it's likely your local network's upload speed that is the bottleneck.