# AWS S3 browser upload: Invalid Policy Invalid JSON error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to an S3 machine directly from the browser, bypassing sending to my server.

I've read the relevant post from amazon [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434), and the full javascript example posted as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n/12378395#12378395). However when I attempt the javascript solution I receive the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
<Message>Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON.</Message>
<RequestId>2F09C5449F42E3AF</RequestId>
<HostId>m++SN+V5bjFFkG0Qa5ceDveS5bBSvjFhcXANlyf2Ay11Llld3EEa54cT7rpg0cjhKLA0ItrnPgg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

On the server side I generate my policy and sign it using the [s3policy package](https://github.com/arbitrarytech/s3policy) Edit: included signed policy example below:

```
var policy = {s3PolicyBase64: "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNi00MS0yOVQxOjI0OjI4WiIsIm…sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCIiXV19", s3Signature: "JlZ6UdDWVhHoeiu5urdTtQupkO0=", s3Key: "AKIAJ6LFZZBY24MBQ4GA"}
```

Here is the code I'm using in the browser to generate a form and submit my post:

```
  var fd = new FormData();
  // Populate the Post paramters.
  fd.append('key', key);
  fd.append('Content-Type', content_type);
  fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', policy["s3Key"]);
  fd.append('acl', 'private');
  fd.append('success_action_redirect', "https://attachments.me/upload_callback")
  fd.append('policy', policy["s3PolicyBase64"])
  fd.append('signature',policy["s3Signature"])
  // This file object is retrieved from a file input.
  fd.append('file', $('#file_'+id)[0].files[0]);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

  xhr.open('POST', dest_url, true); //MUST BE LAST LINE BEFORE YOU SEND 

  xhr.send(fd);
```

I've been through the slow process of double checking my outputs, but I'm clueless as to what is causing the invalid policy error. Here is a base64 decoded version of my policy, maybe someone could identify what is invalid about it.

```
{"expiration":"2016-41-29T1:24:28Z",
"conditions":[{"bucket":"intellilease-docs"},["eq","$key","uploads/OK/Stephens/"],{"acl":"private"},["content-length-range",0,null],["starts-with","$Content-Type",""]]}
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your `policy` object please? The thing that your getting `policy["s3Signature"]` and `policy["s3PolicyBase64"]` from (minus any sensitive keys, of course)

Comment: Check your policy again... unless you redacted it, the base64 has an invalid character in it: `WiIsIm…sWyJz`  What is `…` doing there?

Comment: Also suspicious: `["content-length-range",0,null]`... this is valid json, but is it a valid policy?  No number is "less than" NULL, since nothing can be compared to a non-existent value, so it seems odd that this would be valid.

Comment: Michael, your comment was the solution here. I changed content-length-range to have a number on the maximum end and the invalid json error went away. If you will post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: In my case, at the backend i was using mime.getType(req.body.filetype); for "Content-Type". This was giving null.  Fixing that, resolved issue for me.