# How to set content type while uploading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading a file to s3 bucket. While the uploading need to find file extension and need to add it correct content type.

```js
$('#upload-files').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fileName = data.files[0].name;
  var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
  if (ext == "pdf") {
    console.log(data);
    data.submit();
  } else {
    alert("Upload Pdf images only");
    return false;
  }
})
```

How to add its content-type before upload.

Comment: If you're sending this data through a HTML `<form>` element then the content-type header will be set for you automatically by the browser, based on the content of the selected file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am uploading file through jquery how to set its content type through jquery.

Comment: So you're sending this via jQuery AJAX? In which case it would have made more sense to show that logic. In this case simply use the `contentType` property of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Image to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to send data to server:

```js
public formdata = new FormData();
onSubmit() {
  this.resetform(); //Order matters here
  let headers: any = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-type', 'undefined');

  formData.append("selectFile", this.formData);
  const req5 = new HttpRequest('POST', 'url as hosted on TOMCAT', formData,
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'text'
  });

  return this.httpClient.request(req5).subscribe(e => {
    (console.log(e);)
  }
}

resetform() {
  this.formData = new FormData();
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have not written whole code, I am trying to explain that this code will be helpful to send file to server.

Comment: I'd argue that it won't be helpful at all as it will only generate multiple errors.